# How to specify the tar final structure

Tags: linux, tar

I have this structure:

```
release/folder1/file1
release/folder2/file2
...
release/folderN/fileN
```

I want to include all those folders (folder1, folder2 ... folderN) in a tar file.
The key is that I want these folders to be in the final tar within another directory named **MYAPP** so when you open the tar you can see this:

```
MYAPP/folder1/file1
MYAPP/folder2/file2
...
MYAPP/folderN/fileN
```

How can I achieve this without renaming the original "release" directory and/or creating new directories. 
Is this possible to achive just in the tar process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
--transform=s@^release/@MYAPP/@
```

to your `tar` command line.

The argument of the `--transform` command line is a command that is passed to `sed` together with the file path before it is stored in the archive (use `tar -tf` to show the names of the files stored in the archive).

The command `s@^release/@MYAPP/@` tells sed to search (`s`) `release/` at the beginning of the string (`^`) and replace it with `MYAPP/`.

The `/` at the end of the search and replace strings is needed to be sure the complete name of the component is `release` (to not replace `release.txt`). The `@` character is just a regex delimiter. Usually `/` is used as a regex delimiter but we prefer to use a different delimiter here to avoid the need to escape `/` (because it is used in the search and replace strings).

Read more in the documentation of [`tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html) and [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: Thanks! The command transform seems to be what I was needing.